# Autofill Amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this split function which I can add more fields by clicking the button. My Problem are if I add a field I can't get the exact amount and back the amount if I remove the field.

**Sample Scenario:**

[image]

The above image show the initial amount **-1,000.50**. Now these are my problems.

[image]

1. I input `50` in the amount of first field which result to `Payee: 1 [-950.50]` as the remaining amount for payee. When I add another field it's auto fill the amount and I expect `-950.50` because that's the remaining amount. But what I get is the initial amount `-1,000.50` in the second field. **How to get the updated remaining amount?**
2. If I remove the added field I want to added back the amount. For ex. if the field has `50` and the remaining amount is `-950.50`. If I remove the field that contains amount of  `50` it must be added back in the remaining amount and it will be `-1,000.50`. **How to added back the amount?**

Here are what I have tried:

**split.html**

```
<table id="dataTable" class="calendar fluid" data-calendar-options='{"maxHeight":70}'"
    <caption> Payee: 1 
        [<span id="remaining">-1,000.50</span>]
    </caption>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="week-end" id="p_scents"><br/>
                *Note: Amount totals must equal transaction total and envelopes must be specified to 
                       enable the split button.<br/><br/>

                <p class="button-height">
                    <span class="input">
                        <label class="button orange-gradient">Envelope #1</label>

                        <select name="env[]" class="envelope select compact">
                            <option value="none">(Select)</option>

                            <optgroup label="Category">
                                <option value="1">Internet</option>
                                <option value="2">Savings</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>

                        <input type="text" name="amt[]" placeholder="0.00" size="10" 
                            id="validation-required" class="input-unstyled input-sep validate[required]"
                            onkeyup="calculate(0)">

                        <input type="text" name="note[]" placeholder="note" class="input-unstyled" id="note">
                    </span>

                    <span class="with-tooltip">
                        <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/icons/tick.png" title="Default">
                    </span>
                </p><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:{}" id="addScnt" class="button orange-gradient icon-plus-round">
                    Another Envelope
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>


<script>
    function calculate(difference) {
        var sum = 0;
        $(":text").each(function() {
            amt = replaceCommaDollar(this.value);
            if(!isNaN(amt) && amt.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(amt);
                total = sum;
                difference = -1,000.50 + total                                  
            }
        });

        $("#remaining").html(numberWithCommas(difference.toFixed(2)));

        if(difference == 0){
            $("#split").html("<button type='submit' class='button orange-gradient'>Split Amount</button>");
        }else{
            $("#split").html("<button type='submit' class='button orange-gradient' disabled='disabled'>Split Amount</button>");
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
        var remain_amount = Math.abs(replaceCommaDollar($("#remaining").text())).toFixed(2);

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {  
            $('<p class="button-height">'+
              ' <span class="input">'+
              '     <label class="button orange-gradient">' + 'Envelope #' + i + '</label>' +
              '     <select name="env[]" class="envelope select compact">'+
              '         <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select)</option>' +
              '         <optgroup label="Category">' +
              '             <option value="1">Internet</option>' +
              '             <option value="2">Savings</option>' +
              '         </optgroup>' +
              '     </select>' +
              '    <input type="text" name="amt[]" id="split-amount' + i + '" placeholder="0.00" size="10" class="input-unstyled input-sep" onkeyup="calculate(0)" value="'+ remain_amount +'">'+
              '    <input type="text" name="note[]" placeholder="note" class="input-unstyled">'+
              ' </span>'+
              ' <a href="javascript:{}" id="remScnt" class="with-tooltip">Remove</a></p><br/\>'
              ).appendTo(scntDiv);

             $("#remaining").html('0.00');
             $("#split").html("<button type='submit' class='button orange-gradient'>Split Amount</button>");

             i++;
             return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
            if( i > 2 ) {
                test = $('#split-amount'+i).val();
                alert(test);

                $(this).parents('p').remove();

                i--;
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

1. **How to get the updated remaining amount?** You are calculating `remain_amount` on document ready, instead of when you click the add button. You need to move its calculation within the click handler for `#addScnt`. Just make it the first line of that function and it should recalculate accordingly.
2. **How to added back the amount?** We can do this by reading the value out of the input field we are removing. Here is the modified remove click handler to demonstrate.

   ```
   $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
       // Might not need the if statement
       if (i > 2) {
           //test = $('#split-amount' + i).val();
           //alert(test);

           var $p = $(this).parents('p');

           // Consider this approach to getting the removed value
           var textValue = $p.find('input[name="amt[]"]').val();
           var numValue = replaceCommaDollar(textValue);

           var $remaining = $("#remaining");
           var remainingValue = replaceCommaDollar($remaining.text());
           var difference = remainingValue - numValue;

           var newRemainingValue = numberWithCommas(difference.toFixed(2)))
           $("#remaining").text(newRemainingValue);

           $p.remove();

           // This might not be needed anymore
           i--;
       }

       return false;
   });
   ```

Note that given my approach to obtaining the removed value, you might be able to get rid of the logic involving `i` unless you have other work to do. Consider searching the DOM based on the element you're removing. This *is* probably slower to execute, but not unreasonably so. It's your choice though and it shouldn't matter too much either way. I think my suggestion is easier to maintain, and if I were to optimize there are other aspects of this page that deserve more attention.

I also recommend creating a functional jsFiddle in the future, your problem would have been much easier to test and solve with a functioning example. I tried creating one, but I had to alter the HTML and JavaScript too significantly, as there are missing JavaScript functions in the source you provided.

I hope that helps! Feel free to ask any questions regarding my answer, but please don't expand the scope of your original problem.

Comment: I try but it's not working in jsfiddle. I don't know how to use it. I will just put in your answer the remaining script

Comment: The remaining scripts shouldn't matter. I'm going to remove the code you added as it's not pertinent to my answer.